# How to add image to my FB post update using Facebook SDK? Android

Tags: android, facebook

I have figured out how to successfully post to Facebook using text, and also adding a link. However, I am not sure how to send an image with it. I do not have a URL, I have a URI. I want to be able to post the image using URI to FB. How can I do this? Here is how I posted the text, based off of the Facebook example.

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (pendingAction != PendingAction.NONE &&
                (exception instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException ||
                exception instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException)) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(CameraActivity.this)
                    .setTitle("Cancelled")
                    .setMessage("Unable to perform action")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                    .show();
            pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;
        } else if (state == SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED) {
            handlePendingAction();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("incomplete-switch")
    private void handlePendingAction() {
        PendingAction previouslyPendingAction = pendingAction;
        // These actions may re-set pendingAction if they are still pending, but we assume they
        // will succeed.
        pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;

        switch (previouslyPendingAction) {
            case POST_STATUS_UPDATE:
                postStatusUpdate();
                break;
        }
    }

    private interface GraphObjectWithId extends GraphObject {
        String getId();
    }

    private void showPublishResult(String message, GraphObject result, FacebookRequestError error) {
        String title = null;
        String alertMessage = null;
        if (error == null) {
            title = "Success";
            String id = result.cast(GraphObjectWithId.class).getId();
            alertMessage = getString(R.string.successfully_posted_post, message, id);
        } else {
            title = "Error";
            alertMessage = error.getErrorMessage();
        }

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(alertMessage)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                .show();
    }

    private FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder createShareDialogBuilder() {
        Log.d(TAG, "createShareDialogBuilder()");
        return new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
                .setName("CamAcc")
                .setDescription("Check out this new image taken with CamAcc!")
                .setLink("http://developers.facebook.com/android");
    }

    private void postStatusUpdate() {
        if (canPresentShareDialog) {
            FacebookDialog shareDialog = createShareDialogBuilder().build();
            uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
        } else if (user != null && hasPublishPermission()) {
            final String message = getString(R.string.status_update, user.getFirstName(), (new Date().toString()));
            Request request = Request
                    .newStatusUpdateRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), message, place, tags, new Request.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            showPublishResult(message, response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());
                        }
                    });
            request.executeAsync();
        } else {
            pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE;
        }
    }

    private boolean hasPublishPermission() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        return session != null && session.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions");
    }


    private void performPublish(PendingAction action, boolean allowNoSession) {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null) {
            pendingAction = action;
            if (hasPublishPermission()) {
                // We can do the action right away.
                handlePendingAction();
                return;
            } else if (session.isOpened()) {
                // We need to get new permissions, then complete the action when we get called back.
                session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSION));
                return;
            }
        }

        if (allowNoSession) {
            pendingAction = action;
            handlePendingAction();
        }
    }
```

My thoughts were to put it into a Bundle, but I did not know how to send it off. So what I did was this:

```
byte[] byteData = null;
                    String filename = pictureUri.toString();
                    Log.i(TAG, "FB path: " + filename);

                    Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                    byteData = baos.toByteArray();

                    try {
                        Bundle params = new Bundle();
                        params.putByteArray("source", byteData);

                        Request request = new Request(
                            Session.getActiveSession(),
                            "me/objects/app_name:feed", //"me/app_name:post",
                            params,
                            HttpMethod.POST
                        );

                        Response response = request.executeAndWait();
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
```

What should I add to my postStatusUpdate() method to make this work? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
Try to do like this in your postStatusUpdate() Method      

private void postStatusUpdate() {
                if (canPresentShareDialog) {
                    FacebookDialog shareDialog = createShareDialogBuilder().build();
                    uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
                } else if (user != null && hasPublishPermission()) {
                    final String message = getString(R.string.status_update, user.getFirstName(), (new Date().toString()));

                            String filename = pictureUri.toString();
                            Log.i(TAG, "FB path: " + filename);
                            Bundle postParams=new Bundle();
                            Bitmap image =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename);
                            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                            postParams.putString("link", "Message You want to add");
                            postParams.putByteArray("photo", byteArray);
                            Request request=new Request(session,"me/photos", postParams,  HttpMethod.POST,new Request.Callback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                                    showPublishResult(getString(R.string.photo_post), response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());
                                }
                            });
                            request.executeAsync();
                } else {
                    pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Nope, does not work.The image is not attached. Any other ideas? I will add +1 for effort/response though.